# Codeigniter libraries params

Tags: php, class, codeigniter

Sometime ago i added some params to a library, and it worked just fine ... i dont know if i messed up with some configuration setting or what, right now i cant pass the exact same params.

The library Template:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Template {

        public $config = array();



        public function __construct($params = NULL)
        {   

                echo '<pre>'; print_r($params); echo '</pre>';
                /*This should print the array (and it's printing nothing):

                Array
                (
                     [menus] => Array
                       (
                            [Administradores] => index
                            [Logs] => logs
                       )

                )*/

            if ($params){
                foreach ($params as $key => $value){
                    $this->config[$key] = $value;
                }
            }

        }

        public function cms_template($pagina=NULL, $modulo=NULL, $titulo=NULL, $data=NULL, $dir='backoffice')
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->library('session');
            if (isset($this->config['menus']))
                $menus = $this->config['menus'];
            else
                $menus=NULL;

            $dados['dados'] = array(
                'id_administrador' => $CI->session->userdata('id_administrador'),
                'email' => $CI->session->userdata('email'),
                'nome' => $CI->session->userdata('nome'),
                'modulo' => $modulo,
                'titulo' => $titulo,
                'menus' => $menus
            );

            $CI->load->view($dir.'/topo', $dados);
            $CI->load->view($dir.'/'.$pagina, $data);
            $CI->load->view($dir.'/rodape');    
        }
```

The controller:

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->auth_model->verificaLogin('id_administrador','backoffice/login');
        $this->load->model('administradores_model');
        $params=array(
            'menus' => array(
                'Administradores'=>'index',
                'Logs'=>'logs'
            )
        );

        $this->load->library('template', $params);
    }
```

When i run it, it throws me n error on the view:

```
<?php
            foreach ($dados['menus'] as $key => $value) {
                echo '<li>'.active_anchor('/'.$this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$value, $key, '/'.$this->uri->uri_string()).'</li>';
            }
            ?>
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach()

Comment: You are right, i didn't noticed i used the same word, but actually it does work fine and it's not affecting the returned data, so the problem is not there. But thanks for pointing me that. It's corrected now.

Comment: What happens if instead of `$dados['menus']` you use just `foreach($dados as $key=>$value)` ?

Comment: ah that was okay, don't fix it.
now try to add some tracing to the line: `$menus=NULL;`

Comment: `$menus=NULL` can become `$dados['menus']` and `NULL` does not work in `foreach`. Try `$menus=array()` instead.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.
Jorge: i have more data in that array and it prints what is supposed to however, the $data['menus'] is empty or null.

hakre: that stopped the error, but it is still empty.

I think the problem is in this line: `$this->load->library('template', $params);` whatever i pass in the $params var, it just dont make it to the library.

This is weirds, because, i didnt touch this code for a few days, and im pretty sure it used to work sometime ago. It must me something i changed in other files. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Well, it was not easy. After a few hours testing everything, i found that if i auto load the library, the params just stop working.

Dont know if this is a bug, or a principle of Code Igniter, but at least i've found the cause.

Any ideas how to solve this? I really need to auto load this library, and i really need to pass params to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About your last comment on why autoloading this library it stops working! This has nothing to do with CodeIgniter, but PHP limitation. There's a name conflict probably.

I'm not sure but remember that PHP has a limitation, your classes must have a unique name. I don't know if "template" is a CI reserved name but try a different name. If this is the case to solve it, you must have a good naming scheme, that's why CI uses suffix and prefixes. Or namespaces, but CI doesn't support it.

Comment: Hi @heldrida There's no conflit. It is simple as this: if you want to pass params to the library, you can't autoload it.